# Degraded SQL Query Speed By Nesting a Single Query inline vs temp table

Tags: postgresql, left-join, temp-tables, postgresql-performance

I have a query of the following, basic form.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.field1,
    b.field2,
    c.agg_values
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.something = b.something
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        array_to_string(array_agg(label), ';;') AS agg_values,
        some_table.some_field
    FROM some_table
    WHERE some_table.some_field = 'some-fixed-value'
    GROUP BY some_field
) AS c ON a.some_field = c.some_field
WHERE a.some_other_field = 'some-other-fixed-value'
```

There's nothing too wild about this query.  Pretty run of the mill!

This query runs pretty slow in my Postgres 9.4.5 (~4 minutes), where I have maybe 15k records returned total.  `some_table` has probably ~10k records.

If I move the content of that `LEFT JOIN` sub-query to a temp table and left join from the temp table, my performance increases substantially.  My query may take only 15s now, vs 240s.  To be more explicit, if I remove `SELECT array_to_string ... GROUP BY some_field` query, and put that query into a temp table, then left join on that temp table, BAM, fast.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table_c ( ... );
INSERT INTO temp_table_c SELECT ... same query nested in LEFT JOIN from before ...;
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.field1,
    b.field2,
    c.agg_values
FROM a
INNER JOIN ON a.something = b.something
LEFT JOIN temp_table_c AS c ON a.some_field = c.some_field
WHERE a.some_other_field = 'some-other-fixed-value'
```

I would appreciate it if someone could explain why the `TEMP TABLE` version of the query is so much more performant.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you think that the precise DDL of your `temp_table_c` is a bit pertinent?

Comment: Attach execution plans, please. Run EXPLAIN ANALYZE. The slow plan can be slow due wrong estimations. Using temp table enforce different estimations and different plan. The EXPLAIN can help to visualize.

Comment: Thanks, both.  I have attached both raw queries and the EXPLAIN ANALYZE of both.  Very suspiciously, my low performing query (which I've called `normal-raw.sql` is running very quickly today.  We have negligible weekend activity, but heavy work-week activity (all hours).  What was 240s now dropped down to 7s with absolutely 0 changes.  Very peculiar.  The temp table query, which I mentioned generally takes ~15s to run also completed in under 10s.  I have attached the files here:  http://cdaringe.com/c/pub/misc/query-debugging/nested-selects/  .  I will try them again while we are under load.

Comment: Performance has since degraded once more as originally described in the problem statement.  That would suggest to me that server load is affecting the performance, however, I still don't see why the SQL structure would impact it